# Android GCM push notification (remote) works on emulator but not real device

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using React-Native to build Android app, and using react-native-push-notification to handle push notification.
I followed the configuration from the library which is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and

```
<receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
  <service
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

I could manage the REMOTE push notification working in emulator, but not in device, do anyone know why?
I don't think this is much to do with react-native, since it's a GCM REMOTE push notification, not a local push notification that triggered by react-native.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Could you try using the newer version which is [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and see if you this still happens?

Comment: @AL. Thank you very much for your comment, but our company is using AWS SNS, and it doesn't seem have other options except GCM.